# How to use weka package manager with proxy in windows?

Tags: java, proxy, package, classpath, weka

I'm trying to set proxy for weka 3.7 package manager like this tutorial:

https://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager%3F#GUI package manager-Using a HTTP proxy

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=some.proxy.somewhere.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=port weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

I have already check the path and classpath and weka runs with runweka.bat without any problem.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution after playing with the paths;

knb answer is correct but you need to include weka.jar in the command.

```
java -cp weka.jar -Dhttp.proxyHost=some.proxy.somewhere.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=port weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

Answer (score 0):

The weka.jar file must be on  your classpath. You can set this on the command line with the `-cp`  option.

Run java with

`java -cp <FULL PATH TO weka.jar> -Dhttp.proxyHost=some.proxy.somewhere.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=port weka.gui.GUIChooser`

You might still get some warning messages about "missing jdbc drivers". You can ignore these "error" messages for now.